# What does different namespaces mean in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, namespaces, flex4

I worked on a flex application 6-7 months back. We used flex 3.5 sdk. Now we are upgrading our flex app with flex sdk 4/4.1

I am still new to flex development and I have a very basic question related to namespace.

I have seen three different namespaces in flex sample applications. What is the purpose of having three diff namespaces? When do I use each of them ?

```
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Namespaces are a way of logically grouping code together.  [Here's some more on that from Adobe.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_06.html)

In your particular example, these are [XML Namespaces](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_09.html).

The particular namespaces listed above are listed as they are being used by your Flex application for:

fx - Contains the top-level ActionScript Language elements.

s - Include the Flex Spark components

mx - Contains all the components in the Flex mx.* packages, flex charting & data visualization components.

For more info on these particular namespaces and using XML namespaces in general:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf5f39f-7ff7.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf5f39f-7ff3

Answer (score 2):

Also found out this document that explains upgrading flex app from sdk 3 to sdk 4. This pdf contains explanation of namespaces.
http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/flex/pdfs/upgrading-flex3-to-flex4-techguide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The mx namespace is the original namespace for Flex components. The s namespace points to the newer Spark components, many of which have the same class names (s:Application vs. mx:Application for example). I haven't used the fx namespace yet, but I'm fairly certain it is used for effect and transition declarations, which are done differently than mx effects. Hope that helps.