# HelloWorld in Flex using flash builder 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flexbuilder, flashbuilder4

My code is as follwos;

1, ) Both the label and the button are overlapping. and how can i fix that ? (I know that the layout is set to `absolute` by default, but when i removed the `minWidth="955" minHeight="600"` and included `layout="horizontal"` i got the following error)

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Initializer for 'layout': values of type spark.layouts.supportClasses.LayoutBase cannot be represented in text. HelloFlex.mxml  /HelloFlex/src  line 4  Flex Problem
```

2.) May i know what the tags mean `xmlns:fx` `xmlns:s` `xmlns:mx` and at which instances i should be using them ?

3.) In FLex Builder 4.6, in the design mode can i `Drag-and-drop` components to design the user interface ?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" >
        <fx:Declarations>
            <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->

        </fx:Declarations>
        <mx:Label text="Hello World"/>
        <mx:Button label="Click"/>


    </s:Application>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below code may help you: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout paddingTop="5" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" paddingBottom="5"/>
    </s:layout>
    <mx:Label text="Hello World"/>
    <mx:Button label="Click"/>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thank you that did the trick. Can you help me solve Question 2 and 3 Please ??

Comment: For your Q2 please read below link: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038235/what-does-different-namespaces-mean-in-flex

Comment: Answering your Q3, Yes you can do that. As Flex 4 and above is mostly developed for Look and fill. Even you can use existing layout (Layout provided by Flex Builder for designing).

Answer (score 0):

From this page… https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/Adobe+Flash+Builder+'New+Project'+Bug

> It might be worth noting the other workaround on this wiki page… if you close flash builder and change the line in flex-sdk-description.xml file that says 4.10.0 to 4.9.0
>   This bug stops manifesting.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to open the file template inside of Flash Builder and remove the ${wizard_attributes} tag it also stops embedding layout="absolute".

You can get there via Flash Builder Preferences -> Flash Builder -> File Templates -> MXML -> MXML Web Application and then click edit to remove the attribute.